# is it possible to mark some resources (urls) as http 1.1 only? on a server that offers both http2 and http1.1

Tags: http2, filesize, http-1.1

Please is it possible to mark some resources (urls) as `http1.1` only, on a server that offers both `http2` and `http1.1` ?

Serving large files via `http2` seems to break on [ACE Server](https://github.com/CrowdHailer/Ace).

However these same files are served without issues via `http1.1` on the same server.

How may we have both protocols available on the same server, while some resources restricted to just `http1.1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Client and server negotiate what protocol to use (`http/1.1` vs `http/2`) on a *connection* basis.

This means that the protocol that will be spoken on that connection is decided well before an HTTP request is sent on that connection.

For this reason, the typical way to separate HTTP/1.1 from HTTP/2 is to use different subdomains, so that clients can open HTTP/1.1 connections to `https://http.domain.com` and HTTP/2 connections to `https://http2.domain.com`.

However, this also requires to change the resources URL in a way that applications know *a priori* in which subdomain the resource is hosted - this is not ideal.

Your best option is probably to file an issue to the ACE server so that large files are served correctly also via HTTP/2.